# cursor.getCount() returning 1 but should have returned 0

Tags: java, android

I have a query which is

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total FROM transactions WHERE transaction_date > 1477333800
```

For this query, `cursor.getCount()` is returning `1`. But when iterating through the cursor, the value is coming up null.

```
public Cursor getTotalForToday(long start)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();        
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) AS total FROM "+TRANSACTION_TABLE+" WHERE transaction_date > "+start, null);
    return c;
}

Cursor cursor = db.getTotalForToday();
if(cursor.getCount() == 0) // this is evaluating to false
{
     forToday.setText("Zero"); //forToday is TextView
}
else
{
   while(cursor.moveToNext())
   {
       String total_today = cursor.getString(0); // this is returning null
       forToday.setText(total_today);
   }
}
```

PS: The data type of `amount` is integer in the table

If I query the same thing in SQLLite Firefox extension, I'm getting the following output
[image: SS1]

Ideally, the number of rows returned should have been 0, but I have no idea why it is returning as 1.
Here is the data in the table btw:
[image: SS2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate SQL functions such as `SUM()` always return a result row. The result itself can be null.

Comment: Darn! This is what I just figured out. The red colored background in the first screenshot was a good hint.